# .net n-Tiered/Distributed Programming Technologies

Tags: .net, n-tier-architecture, distributed-computing

If want to learn how to program n-Tiered/Distributed applications in .net, what technology should I start my learning with COM+/Remoting/Web Services/WCF?

Are these technologies complementary or exclusive and to what degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF is the main topic, it enfolds all the others in one form or another.

- (D)COM(+) is a 'legacy' interface, you don't want to build a new system with that.
- Remoting is dissolved into WCF, you won't see it as a name anymore. WCF with binary formatting and TCP binding replaces it.
- Web Services (WSDL, SOAP) are integrated into WCF. It is implemented in WCF with SOAP formatting and HTTP binding.

Answer (score 4):

COM+/Remoting are old. Lose them.

Web services and WCF are a way to go.

N-tiered and distributed have different focus.

N-tiered means you separate your application is several layers, usually it's a presentation + business logic + data access.

Distributed deals with a distributed nature of your application components. It may have something to do with the distributed hardware infrastructure or with the conceptual distribution, the data sources and services you need to orchestrate to enact your application and provide your own services on top of others.

it's actually a very broad and somewhat vague topic. The talk could go on for years.